# Checkout/Onepage Redirect to Cart Page

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, onepage-checkout, shipping-methods

I am using 1.9.1.0. When I Click **Continue** Button on Shipping Method. The Page Redirect to cart Page. After I analysis the error on js. I have tried disable and enabling the various shipping methods no joy having same issue. 
please help me out from the issue.  I have posted the error below. its taken by browser console.

```
POST https://example.com/checkout/onepage/saveShippingMethod/ 500 Internal Server Error 403ms   c359267...57db.js (line 1530)
```

```
"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - https://example.com/checkout/onepage/saveShippingMethod/"
```

The error 1530 line below:-

```
this.transport.send(this.body);
```

The Below Steps are already done:-
1. Changing the file permissions
2. Increasing memory_limit

Error on system.log:-

> 2016-11-17T09:21:22+00:00 ERR (3): Strict Notice: Declaration of Sm_Market_Block_Page_Html_Head::addItem() should be compatible with Extendware_EWCore_Block_Override_Mage_Page_Html_Head::addItem($type, $name = NULL, $params = NULL, $if = NULL, $cond = NULL)  in /usr/share/nginx/html/includes/src/Sm_Market_Block_Page_Html_Head.php on line 94

and think Extendware_EWCore is not compatible so i was disabled the module. having no joy. same issue happening.

Comment: debug in Sm_Market module

Comment: thinks, its not related to shipping method.

Comment: @JohnS Have You Fixed the issue ?

Comment: @Crock No still having the issue

Comment: May i know , Are you config in new server, and if yes. what are the changes makes in php.ini?

Comment: memory_limit=1024M only changed and checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go and Open again your php.ini config file. Please change the below values

1. **short_open_tag = on**  (remove ; symbol).
2. Change max_execution_time = 30 to **max_execution_time = 1800**
3. Change  upload_max_filesize = 2M to **upload_max_filesize = 32M**
4. Change  post_max_size = 8M to **post_max_size = 32M**

Comment: yeah. now working. i dint know how it should be, thanks.

Comment: How do these config changes remedy the issue?